# C# how can I create a constructor to initializes the reference to the listbox, then start a new arrayList?

Tags: c#, reference, listbox

I have a form, inside the form there is a listbox called lstbox, and I have got another class called Test, in this Test class how can I do the above requirement in the title.

Inside the public `Test()`,what do I need to put in this ( )

I have got another class called `Data`, I also need to create an `ArrayList` inside this Test class to store a lot of data object...is it `Data data = new Data();`???

```
    namespace TEST

{

 class Test

    {
       Data data = new Data(); ?????????ArrayList store Data object.

       public Test()
       {


       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the string of question marks will compile.

Answer (score 3):

If you're new to C#, I would start by *avoiding* GUIs. Yes, they're visually rewarding - but there are many aspects of GUI coding which will make it harder for you to learn C#. I suggest you start with simple console applications - learn about collections, IO, and language features.

Beyond that, your question isn't very clear, but I suspect you just need to put code in your constructor, and it sounds like you need to declare another field too:

```
class Test
{
    private ArrayList list;

    public Test()
    {
        list = new ArrayList(); // You could initialize at the point of declaration, too
        list.Add(new Data());
    } 
}
```

I would also *strongly* suggest that you use the generic `List<T>` type instead of the non-generic `ArrayList` type. (Non-generic collections were almost entirely superceded by the generic ones, back in 2005.) You might also want to make your variable read-only, and you could use a *collection initializer* to initialize your list:

```
class Test
{
    // The initialization could go in the constructor if you wanted...
    private List<Data> list = new List<Data>{ new Data() };

    public Test()
    {
    } 
}
```

(It's not at all clear where the list box comes into this, by the way...)

Comment: thanks，but it give me an error,
Error 1 'ASSIGNMENT_1.CalcLine' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments,
this calcline is the Data.

besides what about the constructor that initialize the reference to the listbox part... could you please show me?? thx

Comment: @Theodore: Basically I can't help you while your question is so vague. We've no idea where the listbox is, what the constructor parameters for `CalcLine` are, or what arguments you should provide for them.